# "Defined by me" or "by I" or "by myself"?

Tags: pronouns, passive-voice

I'm writing something and I'm in that position to write "... as will be defined by [me/I/myself]."

I'm so confused which word is the correct one, right now I'm seriously considering "by Yours truly," I need help.

Comment: It depends on the context. For example, if you were writing a business proposal, it might be considered weak if you use the passive voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of "me/I/myself" is really appropriate here. I would use the active "as I will define".

Comment: I agree this would be better, but "as will be defined by me" is grammatical and works as an English sentence. The other two don't make sense.